# Where is it better to validate owner of some document?

Tags: architecture, application-design

We have a WCF-service with a method that, for example, cancels an order by given id.
This method can be called from the web by any user of our site.

Somewhere inside this method we have to check that order with given id belongs to the user that is currently logged in (we read authorization cookies).

*Where is it better to perform this check?*

In WCF method we start business process and somewhere inside it we ask a repository to load an order by id.

We can have a number of such opened-to-web operations. And I want to make the possibility to forget to make such an ownership check as low as possible - I want to implement such a check in some narrow place which every code branch will go though.

I can make such a check in the very repository, but I'm now sure that this kind of validation is of its responsibility.
Also I can implement some kind of declarative validation by applying a behavior attribute to the service or its operations, but I'm not sure this is the right place, because we would have to load an order at least twice - first when performing an ownership test, and then in the business-process.

Answer (score 1):

Every service has a responsibility as a *security boundary*. Therefore, the service method should perform a validation call of its input parameters before it calls the necessary business logic. On top of that, you should always fail fast -- if the method call will fail anyway, make sure it fails as soon as possible (see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast).

So have your service method call a validation method (write one validator class per service method), and that method can either throw a validation exception when an action is not allowed, or return a status code. Exceptions are generally preferred since they stop execution and force the call stack to act upon them.

How the validation method works, is another matter. It may call the repository and ask who the owner of the transaction is. However you implement it, the workings are hidden inside the validator class.